# Проблема с установкой фона кнопки

Tags: android, button, background

пытаюсь применить фон к кнопке описал данный фон в папке res/drawable.
Код фона:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape> </item> <item android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"> <solid android:color="#2D2D2D"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Применяю фон к кнопке следующим образом: `btnAnswer1.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/btn_top_border"));`
Ошибки не возникает, но фон кнопки в приложении отличается от того, который я пытаюсь выставить.
Код метода onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ct1 = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.cl1);

        btnSound = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSound);
        btnMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);

        tvLearningWords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLearningWords);
        tvTranscription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTranscription);

        setTitle("Новые слова");

        btnAnswer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer1);
        btnAnswer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer2);
        btnAnswer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer3);
        btnAnswer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer4);
        btnAnswer5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer5);

        btnSound.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnswer1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnswer2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnswer3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnswer4.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnswer5.setOnClickListener(this);

        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MY_SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);
        themen = sp.getString("themen", "Night");
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        btnAnswer1.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/btn_top_border"));

        if (!hasVisited) {
            writeFile();
            readFile();

            startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstStartActivity.class));

            SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
            e.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
            e.commit();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Drawable.createFromPath` разве не с абсолютными путями работает?

Попробуйте лучше:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    btnAnswer1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_top_border));
else
    btnAnswer1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_top_border));
```

или

```
btnAnswer1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_top_border);
```